# coreos - how to get cloud-config from remote url?

Tags: coreos

I'm trying to install a cores in a vm and I'm not sure how I can load the `cloud-config.yml` file from a remote URL, without having to use `coreos-cloudinit` since it's deprecated.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coreos-cloudinit` is deprecated in favour of `ignition`. [Ignition Configs](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/provisioning.html#ignition-config) can indeed be loaded from remote URLs, typically via a `coreos.config.url=` kernel command-line parameter.

However different methods exist for specific providers, so it's better to check the [Supported Platforms](https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/supported-platforms.html) doc and look for the relevant platform.